# Vert.x http client hangs after connection is left idle

Tags: java, vert.x

I am writing my http client in  Java and using vertx-maven-plugin for development. I am facing a issue where if the connection is left idle for long, vertx httpclient is not able to reuse that client.

vert.x version : 2.0.1-final.
here is a gist to analyse the issue.https://gist.github.com/kaushalpanjwani/7086586

If I have my timer running at interval of 1 or 2 minutes I get the response every time, however if I increase it to 5 min. I just get response firstime only.
And, ofcourse if I do keepalive : false, it works fine for any interval.

My webservices are on : Windows 2008 running IIS 7.

I read about an issue similar to this one here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/pW5R23zIfS8

But based on this, it should be fixed in the version I am using!
Let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you didn't exit your connection with the .end function.